# CMake link ordering when using multiple implementations of interface libraries

Tags: gcc, cmake, dependencies, static-libraries, newlib

I have a project with a layer consisting of interface libraries:

```
add_library(I INTERFACE)
```

These interface libraries are then implemented several times, to fit the different environments of applications:

```
add_library(IA STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(IA PUBLIC I)

add_library(IB STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(IB PUBLIC I)
```

There are also application independent libraries, that make use of the interface libraries.

```
add_library(Foo STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(Foo PUBLIC I)

add_library(Bar STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(Bar PUBLIC I)
```

And finally, the application defines which implementation of the interface library layer is being used.

```
add_executable(ExeA ...)
target_link_libraries(ExeA Foo Bar IA)

add_executable(ExeB ...)
target_link_libraries(ExeB Foo Bar IB)
```

Luckily, this is okay, as long as `IA` is listed after `Foo` and `Bar` in the synthesized link command.

However, certain implementations of I make use of the application independent libraries again.
On these environments, the link command line becomes something like this:

```
IA Foo Bar
```

While it should be

```
Foo Bar IA Foo Bar
```

This make sense, because there is no explicit dependency being described that `Foo` / `Bar` depend on `IA` while compiling `ExeA`.

In the simple case, we just get lucky, because it happens to be the default that link command line has the same order as in the `target_link_libraries` call.

I'm working with **gcc-arm-none-eabi** cross compiler. Here's what I've tried:

- `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY`

  Does not seem to work. The generated command line is still the same even with higher numbers.
- `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--start-group")`

  Linking succeeds, but the program does not run properly on the target hardware. Only after connecting a debugger and resetting, it runs. Strange behaviour.

  When I link `Foo` / `Bar` explicitly with `IA` instead of `--start-group`, the command line becomes `Foo Bar IA Foo Bar`, and then everything works fine. But I cannot do this in general, because of `ExeB`.

---

- **Is there a way how I can define that Foo / Bar temporarily depend on IA while compiling ExeA, and temporarily depend on IB while compiling ExeB?**
- **Is there a different approach on how to handle project structured like the one described above?**

Comment: `X cannot link to A and linking fails.` - So X is actually linked with A. Why do not tell that explicitely with `target_link_libraries(X A)`?

Comment: A second program links to Y B. B has the same interface as A, so if I would have X depend on A, both A and B would be compiled.

Comment: What is meaning of `Y (uses headers of X)`? If *Y* **implements** same interface as X, then it should be additional interface library *X_I*, which is linked both by *X* and *Y*. In that case you may separately link *X* to *A* and *Y* to *B*.

Comment: A, B, C implement I. X uses I, Y uses X, App1 uses Y + A. App2 uses Y + B. App3 uses Y + C. Sorry for the confusion.